# Angular Js Drag and Drop Material md-list

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angularjs-material

Im a newbie with angularJS and wondered if there is any way to add to the example from the docs md-list the drag and drop feature ? 
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.list
Im neither experienced with jquery.
Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This thread is not an answer though - but describes some further aspects of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498109/can-we-drag-and-drop-md-list-item-or-md-cards-in-angular-material-design