# Can we drag and drop md-list item or md-cards in angular material design

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Can we drag and drop md-list item or md-cards in angular material design using  jQuery or other framework?

Comment: Have you made any research on this subject?

Comment: I think I can clarify this question a little. "Motion provides meaning" is supposed to be a core principles of Material Design, and Angular Material is supposed to implement those principles. So one would expect to find support built into Angular Material for dragging cards around in an `md-list` for example. Reading through all the documentation on http://material.angularjs.org, I (probably like the original poster) find no hint of that though. It's such a startling omission I feel I must have missed something.

Comment: This tool is not really an answer - but maybe an alternative in some use cases: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-widget-engine (widget with drag-n-drop support)

Answer (score 3):

I can give a partial answer to this. It is not recommended to add jQuery to an Angular project. Angular is controller-centric while jQuery is focused on manipulating the DOM. They are really different approaches, and while you could possibly get something to work using jQuery and Angular together--it would tend to be a fragile and overly complex solution.

The same holds for Angular Material. It's not a great basis for jQuery operations.

That having been said, see also my comment on your question. I read through all the documentation on http://material.angularjs.org and found nothing that suggests built-in support for drag/drop operations in general nor for dragging cards around in a list.

I realize the framework is still pretty new but I am surprised to find that something as essential to the Material Design concept as dragging cards around a list simply wasn't addressed. So perhaps you and I both are confused or missing something that should be glaringly obvious.